# Blog template should be specific about attribution requirements

Tags: feature-request, blog

The main site template says (in the footer)

> site design / logo © 2012 stack exchange inc; 
>   user contributions licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)

but the blog template just says:

> Stack Exchange © 2011 [Entries (RSS)](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/feed/) and [Comments (RSS)](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/comments/feed/). [CC-Wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

The blog template should be clearer about how attribution should be done (so that somebody reposting doesn't have to guess), like the attribution requirements on our main site.

Comment: Does [this gizmodo reposting](http://gizmodo.com/5893966/the-best-bicycle-tail-light) provide sufficient attribution of [this bicycles community blog original post](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/tail-light-review/)? Should they be given something specific about how to provide attribution instead of having to guess?